# Concat parametrized set of columns vectorized

Tags: python, pandas

I need to build a function in pandas that concats a set of columns.
While most of the answers around seem to have hardcoded values I would have to have it somehow parametrized in a function, and **vectorized at dataframe level, avoiding series operations, better vectorized as it's a big df.**

I assume I must have somehow to have a for (also tried reduce) to get the results:

**Input example**

```
'|    | A   | D   |
 |---:|:----|:----|
 |  0 | B   | E   |
 |  1 | C   | F   |'
```

**Expected output**

```
'|    | A   | D   | concat   |
 |---:|:----|:----|:---------|
 |  0 | B   | E   | BE       |
 |  1 | C   | F   | CF       |'
```

**pseudo code**

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A':['B','C'],'D':['E','F']})

def concat_columns(df,columns_concat):
     string_c = pd.DataFrame({'Concat':[]})
     for col in columns_concat:
         string_c['Concat']+=df[col].astype(str)
     return string_c

df_test['concat'] = concat_columns(df_test,['A','D'])
```

This returns the column concat as NaN, not sure if it's even possible

Comment: AD comes from the column headers and BE comes from the row above previous row?

Comment: @ScottBoston fixed sorry, the values are the columns,

Comment: `df['concat'] = df.sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @ScottBoston: modyfing my example then, data types could be integers, datetimes....

Comment: @not_speshal no hardcoded column values

Comment: @ScottBoston just post the answer and will give it to you, thanks!

Comment: `df.astype(str).apply("".join, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sum` with `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[*'BC'],
                   'D':[*'EF'],
                   'E':[pd.Timestamp('now'), pd.Timestamp('now')+pd.Timedelta(days=1)]})

df['concat'] = df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  D                          E                        concat
0  B  E 2021-09-07 08:31:08.684189  BE2021-09-07 08:31:08.684189
1  C  F 2021-09-08 08:31:08.684189  CF2021-09-08 08:31:08.684189
```

Comment: That was pretty much my answer, only thing that I had to do myself is parametrized the set of columns inside a function.

Comment: @AlejandroA Thanks!  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.